# Button label equals to its id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to make the label of the button the same as its ID? 
This would save some work. The name Products and id is the same. So, is it possible to make the button using only id with something like `{{this.id}}`??

```
            <button type="button" id="Products" class="btn btn-link">
              Products
            </button>
```

Comment: Are you using any sort of JS framework or just jQuery/Javascript?

Comment: Please try some approach yourself first and then share your problems/errors with us, if any.

Comment: you can do this by selecting all buttons and changing innerText to id, note you cant have spaces in id so your buttons have to be one word only

Comment: you can use css `attr()` but it's not very accessible: https://jsfiddle.net/eqza3pso/

Comment: multicursor will do this for you.

Comment: <style>  button:after {content: " " attr(id) "";}  </style> 
This worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem like something that would really save you a lot of work, but you could do it using Javascript.

```js
const buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].innerHTML = buttons[i].id;
}
```

```html
<button id="hello-world"></button>
<button id="hello-other-world"></button>
<button id="hello-another-world"></button>
<button id="bye-world"></button>
```

Get all the buttons on the page, for each button, make the inner HTML take the value of the ID. You could edit it to remove the dash, capitalize or modify as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function using vanilla javascript:

```
function fillButtonLabel(buttonId) {
    var button = document.getElementById(buttonId);
    button.innerHTML = button.id;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nbk3hzqp/1/